# Best practices for doing a count using C# driver in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'd like to know the best approach to do a count over a list that is part of a collection, for simplicity I've abstracted to the following model:

```
public class User
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectId> Followers { get; set; }
    public List<ObjectId> Following { get; set; }  
}
```

Just assume that probably the average of followers/ following could be around 2k on each property, I know some people like to pre-calculate the information using [inc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/#Updating-%24inc), is that recommend under the circumstances described above? if that's the case which could be the approach using the C# driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a large number of users (say millions) and you query on this count frequently, why not use a map reduce? From the c# driver you could read the results of the map reduce.

If you have a small number of users (1000s), you could probably use the aggregation framework on demand, depending on how fast you need the query to be. See an example here [Mongo order by length of array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040161/mongo-order-by-length-of-array). From the c# driver you could execute the [aggregation](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/1.6/html/0dab751c-6534-9a3a-1348-70a2ebdff73f.htm)

If you decide to denormalize the count on saves, you can run a migration from the mongo shell to create the initial values via a cursor. See my answer about these types of migrations [MongoDB: schema migration, update or insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889026/mongodb-schema-migration-update-or-insert/20896447#20896447)

Comment: In this case I'd have maybe 500k to 1M of users, but the followers / following could be arround 200 ~ 2k aprox per user, in the case of making a query of a single user to me makes sense to perform a length of array...what do you think?

Comment: Are you only querying this for one user for say their profile page? Or are you querying across your 500K users?

Comment: I'm querying across the 500k but I'm only retrieving only one document per ID, then I need to do the count for following / followers

Comment: Ok so you aren't querying on the count? If so then you can do the count after the document has been deserialized to your c# model using [Array.Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx)