# Meteor collection sort by $size issue

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This is about likes and dislikes on comments. I'd like to sort comments by likeness, so a comment with more likes will appear first. The issue is that comments with dislikes appear before than comments with no dislikes.

What i want:

- Comment A : 1 like 0 dislikes
- Comment B : 0 like 0 dislike
- Comment C : 0 like 1 dislike

What I'm actually getting:

- Comment A : 1 like 0 dislikes
- Comment C : 0 like 1 dislike
- Comment B    : 0 like 0 dislike

My mongo query on my meteor helper:

```
Missatges.find({ topic: 'xxx' }, { sort: { like:{ $size: -1}, dislike:{ $size: 1}, date: -1 } }).fetch();
```

Note that I use $size because like and dislike are arrays of user _id's. 
Here my comment schema:

```
author: {
    type: String

},
authorId: {
    type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id
}
isAnswer: {
    type: Boolean
},
parentId: {
    type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id,
    optional: true
},
date: {
    type: Date
},
topic: {
    type: String
},
likes: {
    type: [SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id]
},
dislikes: {
    type: [SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id]
},
answers: {
    type: [SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id],
    optional: true
},
text: {
    type: String,
    max: 900,        
}
```

Comment: pls show your comment model design

Comment: What ever result it is returning is the way the query, that you are using, should return.

Comment: Maybe it's my english, perhaps it's yours... but sorry, I don't understand your comment @titi23

Comment: The result you are getting by running the query, is right. That is how the query suppose to return. Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040161/mongo-order-by-length-of-array) you can't use `$size` to sort in mongo. One solution is to `fetch` the matching documents and `sort` them in the helper. Here's an example (note this is untested and may require some tweaking):

```
Template.something.helpers({
  sortedThings: function () {
    return Missatges
      .find({ topic: 'xxx' })
      .fetch()
      .sort(function (b, a) {
        var al = a.likes.length;
        var ad = a.dislikes.length;
        var bl = a.likes.length;
        var bd = a.dislikes.length;
        var d1 = a.date;
        var d2 = b.date;

        // compare by likes
        if (al > bl) return 1;
        if (al < bl) return -1;

        // compare by dislikes
        if (ad < bd) return 1;
        if (ad > bd) return -1;

        // compare by date
        if (d1 > d2) return 1;
        if (d1 < d2) return -1;

        // they are equal
        return 0;
      });
  },
});
```

Comment: It should be possible to have the custom sort function passed in the `sort` attribute of the second argument to `find()` itself once [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2730) is fully resolved (I intend to submit a PR soon).

Comment: Thank you David,  finally,  though,  I opted for the solution presented on the link you provided me. I added 2 Number fields to the model: nLike and nUnlikes. It gets more handy even in other use cases I have