# Sort by array length in java mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo database with 4 documents. These documents contain an array with different length.
I want to sort the documents by the length of their array in java with the mongodb driver.
How would i do that?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040161/mongo-order-by-length-of-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation query for this sorts the documents by the array size, desscending:

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { $addFields: { arrSize: { $size: "$arr" } } },
  { $sort: { arrSize: -1 } }
] )
```

The **Java code** using driver version 3.9.0:

```
Bson addFiledsStage = addFields(new Field<Document>("arrSize", new Document("$size", "$arr")));
Bson sortStage = sort(descending("arrSize"));
List<Bson> pipeline = Arrays.asList(addFiledsStage, sortStage);
List<Document> results = new ArrayList<>();
collection.aggregate(pipeline).into(results);   
results.forEach(System.out::println);
```

The required *imports* for the above code:

```
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.*;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Field;
import java.util.*;
```

Comment: is it possible to sort descending?

Comment: Yes, change the code from `sort(ascending("arrSize"))` to `sort(descending("arrSize"))`. I changed the code in the answer, too.

Comment: i got this message "pipeline can not contain a null value"

Comment: I got the correct output, and no errors (tried just now). Are you able to compile the code?

Comment: and this "The method ascending(String) is undefined for the type MYCLASS"

Comment: Do you have all the imports? What is the driver and Java versions you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203918/discussion-between-marcolia-and-prasad).

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in two ways:

1) Add an additional field to your document which will contain the size of this array. And then sort the documents by this field.

2) Using the aggregation framework. Unwind the array and then group it and additionally sum the elements in the array. And then finally sorting it by the size.

```
public void myFunction(){
    List<AggregationOperation> aggregationOperations = new ArrayList<>();
    aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.unwind("myArrayField"));
    aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.group("_id").push("myArrayField").as("myArrayField").sum("1").as("size")
            .first("fieldToPreserve").as("fieldToPreserve")); //preserve fields from first document
    aggregationOperations.add(Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"size"));
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(aggregationOperations), "MyCollection", MyCollection.class).getMappedResults();
}
```