# Spring boot & mongo: how to sort based on length of an array

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm new to this and I need to sort my data. I have defects with an array, called priorities, that has some names in it. Now I want to sort them in descending order based on the length of the array. I'm struggling and can't seem to find how to do this. This is my code:

```
@GetMapping("/defects/sort/priority")
public List<Defect> defects2() { return defectRepository.sortAllDefectByPriority(); }
```

also:

```
@Query("{ $sort: { $size: '$priorities' }: -1 }")
public List<Defect> sortAllDefectByPriority();
```

Can anyone help me?
EDIT: I only know how to use @Query annotations

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040161/mongo-order-by-length-of-array

Comment: Within the query

Comment: To calculate the size of an array you have to use the `$size` aggregation array operator. So, I am not sure you can use the `@Query`, but you can use the `@Aggregation` and get the needed result.

Comment: So you would change it to: `@Aggregation("{ $sort: { $size: '$priorities' }: -1 }")
public List<Defect> sortAllDefectByPriority();`?