# How to sort mongo docs with an array of elements by mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, mongoose

I am using mongodb and using mongoose to manipulate the database.

Here I have a set of docs that I would like to sort them by numbers of elements in the array.

Is there a way to sort them by its array length, in mongoose?

Below is an example of the db. I would like to sort them by the number of tags. OR by the number of likeBy (which is an array of userId)

[image]

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040161/mongo-order-by-length-of-array

Comment: this is also a good reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an auxiliar field to sort by that field like this:

- First `$addFields` to create the auxiliar field which value is the array size using `$size`.
- Then sort by that value
- And `$project` to not show the auxiliar field.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$addFields": {
    "aux_size": {
      "$size": "$tags"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$sort": {
    "aux_size": 1
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "aux_size": 0
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LW-wPIudkAz)

Also, if you are using mongoose I think you won't need this because the model says `tags` fields must be an array. But in case the `tags` fields could be another type (string, number, boolean...) you can use `$isArray` to set that documents as length 0 (example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MTJaTbbNzXH)) or to filter them (example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oTHjPIH82Nh))

Comment: this is what i need thanks