# Why is array length 0 considered greatest number in sorting in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection with array field:

```
const collectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
    index: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    required: true,
  },
  topic: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Topic",
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    ref: "User",
  },,
  items: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Item" }],
});
```

I need to get top 5 collections with most items. For this I am using the following code:

```
const collections = await Collection.find({}).sort({ items: 1 }).limit(5);
```

It's working correctly except for document with items length equal to 0. Mongoose is returning document with empty array before document with highest items length.

[image: Result:]

Comment: I don't think that sort is doing what you're expecting. It is _not_ 'sorting the documents in descending order by length of the array'. For one thing, you've requested an ascending sort rather than a descending one. But the main thing is that the semantics here specify that you want to sort the documents based on the _contents_ of the array. Read more [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/release-notes/3.6-compatibility/#array-sort-behavior). To achieve your coal you may need to materialized/compute a new field representing the length and then sort (in descending order) on that.

Comment: It's sorting but -1 and 1 is giving the opposite result, ascending and descending respectively. As for computed/virtual field, If I understood correctly, sorting is not possible based on virtual fields

Comment: If you want to sort based on the array length then you will probably need to use the `$size` operator and then sort. See the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040161/mongo-order-by-length-of-array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we were discussing in the comments, the database is currently not doing what you think. The fact that the 4 sample documents happen to seemingly be coming out in an order based on array length is just a coincidence.

Given the following documents:

```
{ _id: 0, arr: [ 3 ] }
{ _id: 3, arr: [ 6, 7, 8 ] }
{ _id: 4, arr: [ 1, 5 ] }
```

The query `.find({}).sort({ items: 1 })` will return the following:

```
[
  { _id: 4, arr: [ 1, 5 ] }
  { _id: 0, arr: [ 3 ] }
  { _id: 3, arr: [ 6, 7, 8 ] }
]
```

You can see that (with other sample documents) in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HCFG8lG8lqR). Clearly the sorting is not being done based on the length of the array.

As @jQueeny linked to and what I was attempting to refer to was injecting a field during the query. In aggregation that could look like the following (again using `arr` as the name of the field holding the array):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "arrLength": {
        $size: "$arr"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      arrLength: -1
    }
  }
])
```

This yields the result in the expected order as can be seen in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9uOum-ajhMk).

This is different than virtual fields in Mongoose (hence why it is possible). But doing this at runtime forces the aggregation to do a lot more work. If the size of the matching results being sorted is large and/or this operation will be run frequently, then it might make sense for the application to maintain this field directly when the document (in particular the array) is written to. Doing so could allow the sort to be satisfied by an index which would be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer

Answer (score 0):

The Mongoose version of the accepted answer:

```js
Collection.aggregate()
  .addFields({ arrLength: { $size: "$arr" }})
  .sort({ arrLength: -1 });
```